# Center align a div with a fixed top

Tags: css, html

I have a table containing 3 buttons on the top of my page. I also have a div (below this table) and I'd like to put this on the middle of the screen. I wrote this code:

```
#walkthrough {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 85%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
```

Then I have an element like this: `<div id="walkthrough"> test </div>`. This div is center aligned according with the **width** of my screen, and it's fine.

By the way, looking at the **height**, the div is center-aligned with all the screen size, but I have to consider the bar with the buttons. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/328/).

If the height of my div is too big, it goes over the buttons, and I don't want this to happen. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRotI.png) picture shows what is the result now, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgl3l.png) shows what I am trying to get.

I need the div center aligned on the height, but without going over the buttons.

Any ideas?

Comment: try remove position:absolute; from #walkthrough, here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/331/

Comment: #walkthrough {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    .
    .
}
make the position relative to the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`absolute` positioned element will be removed from the normal flow of the document and will be placed in an exact location on the page. It is also taken out of the normal flow of the document - it won't affect how the elements before it or after it in the HTML are positioned on the Web page.**

Use

```
#walkthrough {
    position: relative;
}
```

Instead of

```
#walkthrough {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/343/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change the top navigation from a table (should never do this) to a `ul` instead.  Then make the div `position: relative`